# CMake include shared library in compilation

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries, libraries, cpack

I can compile my c++ application, but it depends on a **shared** library which can be installed through the packet manager. My problem is that the target device has no internet access. Therefore it can't install the library (and I cannot find the binaries online).

Can I include the shared library in my compiled file(s)/ also compile it (into the build directory)? I thought about including it as a static library, but couldn't find a way how to do this in cmake.

I dug a bit into CPack, but I couldn't find a viable solution so far (please tell me if I am wrong).

Problems with Licensees do not occur, because it is just for a small private project.

Comment: In such a situation I would recommend that you download the source for the library, and build a static version of it to use for deployment.

Comment: This might be a case for [`install(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY_SET)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#runtime-dependency-set).